# OS X Server Workgroup Manager takes very long to load

Tags: networking, ldap, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard, workgroup

When I open Workgroup Manager on the mac mini server it takes forever to load. I have changed the servers DNS to it's 'public' IP instead of it's loopback address, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had a .local domain configured, not a good idea (as also stated in the docs). Using something else now, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the server's fully qualified domain name (FQDN).